# Install alongside windows option not appearing, ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: ubuntu, system-installation, grub

I am new to linux, I was trying to install linux 18.04.05 but the installation menu  says:
the computer currently has windows boot manager on. What would you like to do ?
But there is no option of install alongside windows.

Windows is also not showing in the grub menu. I am working on a thinkpad x1 carbon gen 4, with hibernation, fastboot and secure boot disabled.

I previously install ubuntu 20.04 but uninstalled it because I realized I needed 18.04. Not sure if that can have an effect.

I ran bootrepair thne link is paste.ubuntu.com/p/dGc9vYGzGR/
It says additional repair win legacy basic fix but the bios is in uefi only

Thanks for the help

Comment: is the windows partition encrypted?

Comment: No, it's not...